# Python: how to reshape a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am trying to append 10 arrays to a list. The arrays have dimensions `(400,)` and I would like to have a list with shape,  `shape(myList) = (10,)`, where each component has shape `(400,2)`, such as `shape(myList[0]) = (400,2)`.

This is what I am doing:

```
myList = []
for i in range(0,10):
    cordsX = X[i] # len 400
    cordsY = Y[i] # len 400
    myList.append(np.array(list(zip(cordsX, cordsY))))
```

however the shape of `myList` is the following

```
shape(myList)
(10, 400, 2)
```

Comment: Do you mean NumPy arrays? Python lists have no "shape".

Comment: well if I do `shape(myList)` returns `(10, 400, 2)` but I would like `(10,)`

Comment: So you need to change the `shape` function? We don't know what it is.

Comment: it is a default function on `python3.8`. I did not define anything

Comment: Can you share a link to its documentation? It's not listed here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html

Comment: is a module of `numpy` `Help on function shape in module numpy:

shape(a)
    Return the shape of an array.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array_like
        Input array.
    
    Returns
    -------
    shape : tuple of ints
        The elements of the shape tuple give the lengths of the
        corresponding array dimensions.
    
    See Also
    --------
    len
    ndarray.shape : Equivalent array method.`

Comment: I assume you imported numpy like `from numpy import *` and then using `numpy.shape()` as just `shape()`

Comment: `np,.shape` first does `temp=np.array(alist)` and then returns `temp.shape`.  A list only has a `len`.

Comment: If you write something like this - `from numpy import *;li=[1,2,3,4]; print(shape(li))`, it will still work. Although, would **not promote** this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is to return `shape(myList) = (10,)`, assuming that this mysterious *shape* function has behavior similar to the shape attribute of numpy, this cannot be achieved as (10,) simply means a 1-D array. You are appending an nd-array to your list and thus you cannot have a 1-D array, **BUT**, a workaround could be -

```
class Coords:
    def __init__(self, coords) -> None:
        self.coords = coords

myList = []
for i in range(0,10):
    cordsX = X[i] # len 400
    cordsY = Y[i] # len 400
    coords = Coords(np.array(list(zip(cordsX, cordsY))))
    myList.append(coords)

myList = np.array(myList)
print(myList.shape)
print(myList[0].coords.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

`shape` is a numpy function that first makes an array from `myList` and then returns the array's shape.  A list has a `len`, not a `shape`

```
shape(myList)
(10, 400, 2)
```

From this, and your code, I expect

```
len(myList)   # 10

myList[0].shape   # (400,2)
```

It is a list of 10 arrays, all the same shape.

```
myList.shape
```

will raise an error because it's a list, not an array.